# I am trying to create a program that loops through a list of hyperparameters for a machine learning model, much like GridSearchCV does

Tags: python, for-loop, machine-learning, model, hyperparameters

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

digits = load_digits()
df = pd.DataFrame(digits.data, columns=digits.feature_names)
df["target"] = digits.target

X = df.drop(["target"], axis="columns")
y = df.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)


C = [1, 5, 10, 20, 50]
gamma = ["scale", "auto", 0.001, 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1]
kernel = ["linear", "poly", "rbf", "sigmoid", "precomputed"]

a = [C, gamma, kernel]

chl = list(itertools.product(*a))
print(chl)

for i in chl:
print(i)

for i in chl:
        model = SVC(C=chl[i][0], gamma=chl[i][1], kernel=chl[i][2])
        model.fit(X_train, y_train)
        accuracy = model.score(X_test, y_test)
        accuracy_list = []
        accuracy_list.append(accuracy)
print(accuracy_list)
```

```
#Here is my output and the error message generated:
[(1, 'scale', 'linear'), (1, 'scale', 'poly'), (1, 'scale', 'rbf'), (1, 'scale', 'sigmoid'), (1, 'scale', 'precomputed'), (1, 'auto', 'linear'), (1, 'auto', 'poly'), (1, 'auto', 'rbf'), (1, 'auto', 'sigmoid'), (1, 'auto', 'precomputed'), (1, 0.001, 'linear'), (1, 0.001, 'poly'), (1, 0.001, 'rbf'), (1, 0.001, 'sigmoid'), (1, 0.001, 'precomputed'), (1, 0.1, 'linear'), (1, 0.1, 'poly'), (1, 0.1, 'rbf'), (1, 0.1, 'sigmoid'), (1, 0.1, 'precomputed'), (1, 0.5, 'linear'), (1, 0.5, 'poly'), (1, 0.5, 'rbf'), (1, 0.5, 'sigmoid'), (1, 0.5, 'precomputed'), (1, 0.6, 'linear'), (1, 0.6, 'poly'), (1, 0.6, 'rbf'), (1, 0.6, 'sigmoid'), (1, 0.6, 'precomputed'), (1, 0.7, 'linear'), (1, 0.7, 'poly'), (1, 0.7, 'rbf'), (1, 0.7, 'sigmoid'), (1, 0.7, 'precomputed'), (1, 0.8, 'linear'), (1, 0.8, 'poly'), (1, 0.8, 'rbf'), (1, 0.8, 'sigmoid'), (1, 0.8, 'precomputed'), (1, 0.9, 'linear'), (1, 0.9, 'poly'), (1, 0.9, 'rbf'), (1, 0.9, 'sigmoid'), (1, 0.9, 'precomputed'), (1, 1, 'linear'), (1, 1, 'poly'), (1, 1, 'rbf'), (1, 1, 'sigmoid'), (1, 1, 'precomputed'), (5, 'scale', 'linear'), (5, 'scale', 'poly'), (5, 'scale', 'rbf'), (5, 'scale', 'sigmoid'), (5, 'scale', 'precomputed'), (5, 'auto', 'linear'), (5, 'auto', 'poly'), (5, 'auto', 'rbf'), (5, 'auto', 'sigmoid'), (5, 'auto', 'precomputed'), (5, 0.001, 'linear'), (5, 0.001, 'poly'), (5, 0.001, 'rbf'), (5, 0.001, 'sigmoid'), (5, 0.001, 'precomputed'), (5, 0.1, 'linear'), (5, 0.1, 'poly'), (5, 0.1, 'rbf'), (5, 0.1, 'sigmoid'), (5, 0.1, 'precomputed'), (5, 0.5, 'linear'), (5, 0.5, 'poly'), (5, 0.5, 'rbf'), (5, 0.5, 'sigmoid'), (5, 0.5, 'precomputed'), (5, 0.6, 'linear'), (5, 0.6, 'poly'), (5, 0.6, 'rbf'), (5, 0.6, 'sigmoid'), (5, 0.6, 'precomputed'), (5, 0.7, 'linear'), (5, 0.7, 'poly'), (5, 0.7, 'rbf'), (5, 0.7, 'sigmoid'), (5, 0.7, 'precomputed'), (5, 0.8, 'linear'), (5, 0.8, 'poly'), (5, 0.8, 'rbf'), (5, 0.8, 'sigmoid'), (5, 0.8, 'precomputed'), (5, 0.9, 'linear'), (5, 0.9, 'poly'), (5, 0.9, 'rbf'), (5, 0.9, 'sigmoid'), (5, 0.9, 'precomputed'), (5, 1, 'linear'), (5, 1, 'poly'), (5, 1, 'rbf'), (5, 1, 'sigmoid'), (5, 1, 'precomputed'), (10, 'scale', 'linear'), (10, 'scale', 'poly'), (10, 'scale', 'rbf'), (10, 'scale', 'sigmoid'), (10, 'scale', 'precomputed'), (10, 'auto', 'linear'), (10, 'auto', 'poly'), (10, 'auto', 'rbf'), (10, 'auto', 'sigmoid'), (10, 'auto', 'precomputed'), (10, 0.001, 'linear'), (10, 0.001, 'poly'), (10, 0.001, 'rbf'), (10, 0.001, 'sigmoid'), (10, 0.001, 'precomputed'), (10, 0.1, 'linear'), (10, 0.1, 'poly'), (10, 0.1, 'rbf'), (10, 0.1, 'sigmoid'), (10, 0.1, 'precomputed'), (10, 0.5, 'linear'), (10, 0.5, 'poly'), (10, 0.5, 'rbf'), (10, 0.5, 'sigmoid'), (10, 0.5, 'precomputed'), (10, 0.6, 'linear'), (10, 0.6, 'poly'), (10, 0.6, 'rbf'), (10, 0.6, 'sigmoid'), (10, 0.6, 'precomputed'), (10, 0.7, 'linear'), (10, 0.7, 'poly'), (10, 0.7, 'rbf'), (10, 0.7, 'sigmoid'), (10, 0.7, 'precomputed'), (10, 0.8, 'linear'), (10, 0.8, 'poly'), (10, 0.8, 'rbf'), (10, 0.8, 'sigmoid'), (10, 0.8, 'precomputed'), (10, 0.9, 'linear'), (10, 0.9, 'poly'), (10, 0.9, 'rbf'), (10, 0.9, 'sigmoid'), (10, 0.9, 'precomputed'), (10, 1, 'linear'), (10, 1, 'poly'), (10, 1, 'rbf'), (10, 1, 'sigmoid'), (10, 1, 'precomputed'), (20, 'scale', 'linear'), (20, 'scale', 'poly'), (20, 'scale', 'rbf'), (20, 'scale', 'sigmoid'), (20, 'scale', 'precomputed'), (20, 'auto', 'linear'), (20, 'auto', 'poly'), (20, 'auto', 'rbf'), (20, 'auto', 'sigmoid'), (20, 'auto', 'precomputed'), (20, 0.001, 'linear'), (20, 0.001, 'poly'), (20, 0.001, 'rbf'), (20, 0.001, 'sigmoid'), (20, 0.001, 'precomputed'), (20, 0.1, 'linear'), (20, 0.1, 'poly'), (20, 0.1, 'rbf'), (20, 0.1, 'sigmoid'), (20, 0.1, 'precomputed'), (20, 0.5, 'linear'), (20, 0.5, 'poly'), (20, 0.5, 'rbf'), (20, 0.5, 'sigmoid'), (20, 0.5, 'precomputed'), (20, 0.6, 'linear'), (20, 0.6, 'poly'), (20, 0.6, 'rbf'), (20, 0.6, 'sigmoid'), (20, 0.6, 'precomputed'), (20, 0.7, 'linear'), (20, 0.7, 'poly'), (20, 0.7, 'rbf'), (20, 0.7, 'sigmoid'), (20, 0.7, 'precomputed'), (20, 0.8, 'linear'), (20, 0.8, 'poly'), (20, 0.8, 'rbf'), (20, 0.8, 'sigmoid'), (20, 0.8, 'precomputed'), (20, 0.9, 'linear'), (20, 0.9, 'poly'), (20, 0.9, 'rbf'), (20, 0.9, 'sigmoid'), (20, 0.9, 'precomputed'), (20, 1, 'linear'), (20, 1, 'poly'), (20, 1, 'rbf'), (20, 1, 'sigmoid'), (20, 1, 'precomputed'), (50, 'scale', 'linear'), (50, 'scale', 'poly'), (50, 'scale', 'rbf'), (50, 'scale', 'sigmoid'), (50, 'scale', 'precomputed'), (50, 'auto', 'linear'), (50, 'auto', 'poly'), (50, 'auto', 'rbf'), (50, 'auto', 'sigmoid'), (50, 'auto', 'precomputed'), (50, 0.001, 'linear'), (50, 0.001, 'poly'), (50, 0.001, 'rbf'), (50, 0.001, 'sigmoid'), (50, 0.001, 'precomputed'), (50, 0.1, 'linear'), (50, 0.1, 'poly'), (50, 0.1, 'rbf'), (50, 0.1, 'sigmoid'), (50, 0.1, 'precomputed'), (50, 0.5, 'linear'), (50, 0.5, 'poly'), (50, 0.5, 'rbf'), (50, 0.5, 'sigmoid'), (50, 0.5, 'precomputed'), (50, 0.6, 'linear'), (50, 0.6, 'poly'), (50, 0.6, 'rbf'), (50, 0.6, 'sigmoid'), (50, 0.6, 'precomputed'), (50, 0.7, 'linear'), (50, 0.7, 'poly'), (50, 0.7, 'rbf'), (50, 0.7, 'sigmoid'), (50, 0.7, 'precomputed'), (50, 0.8, 'linear'), (50, 0.8, 'poly'), (50, 0.8, 'rbf'), (50, 0.8, 'sigmoid'), (50, 0.8, 'precomputed'), (50, 0.9, 'linear'), (50, 0.9, 'poly'), (50, 0.9, 'rbf'), (50, 0.9, 'sigmoid'), (50, 0.9, 'precomputed'), (50, 1, 'linear'), (50, 1, 'poly'), (50, 1, 'rbf'), (50, 1, 'sigmoid'), (50, 1, 'precomputed')]
(1, 'scale', 'linear')
(1, 'scale', 'poly')
(1, 'scale', 'rbf')
(1, 'scale', 'sigmoid')
(1, 'scale', 'precomputed')
(1, 'auto', 'linear')
(1, 'auto', 'poly')
(1, 'auto', 'rbf')
(1, 'auto', 'sigmoid')
(1, 'auto', 'precomputed')
(1, 0.001, 'linear')
(1, 0.001, 'poly')
(1, 0.001, 'rbf')
(1, 0.001, 'sigmoid')
(1, 0.001, 'precomputed')
(1, 0.1, 'linear')
(1, 0.1, 'poly')
(1, 0.1, 'rbf')
(1, 0.1, 'sigmoid')
(1, 0.1, 'precomputed')
(1, 0.5, 'linear')
(1, 0.5, 'poly')
(1, 0.5, 'rbf')
(1, 0.5, 'sigmoid')
(1, 0.5, 'precomputed')
(1, 0.6, 'linear')
(1, 0.6, 'poly')
(1, 0.6, 'rbf')
(1, 0.6, 'sigmoid')
(1, 0.6, 'precomputed')
(1, 0.7, 'linear')
(1, 0.7, 'poly')
(1, 0.7, 'rbf')
(1, 0.7, 'sigmoid')
(1, 0.7, 'precomputed')
(1, 0.8, 'linear')
(1, 0.8, 'poly')
(1, 0.8, 'rbf')
(1, 0.8, 'sigmoid')
(1, 0.8, 'precomputed')
(1, 0.9, 'linear')
(1, 0.9, 'poly')
(1, 0.9, 'rbf')
(1, 0.9, 'sigmoid')
(1, 0.9, 'precomputed')
(1, 1, 'linear')
(1, 1, 'poly')
(1, 1, 'rbf')
(1, 1, 'sigmoid')
(1, 1, 'precomputed')
(5, 'scale', 'linear')
(5, 'scale', 'poly')
(5, 'scale', 'rbf')
(5, 'scale', 'sigmoid')
(5, 'scale', 'precomputed')
(5, 'auto', 'linear')
(5, 'auto', 'poly')
(5, 'auto', 'rbf')
(5, 'auto', 'sigmoid')
(5, 'auto', 'precomputed')
(5, 0.001, 'linear')
(5, 0.001, 'poly')
(5, 0.001, 'rbf')
(5, 0.001, 'sigmoid')
(5, 0.001, 'precomputed')
(5, 0.1, 'linear')
(5, 0.1, 'poly')
(5, 0.1, 'rbf')
(5, 0.1, 'sigmoid')
(5, 0.1, 'precomputed')
(5, 0.5, 'linear')
(5, 0.5, 'poly')
(5, 0.5, 'rbf')
(5, 0.5, 'sigmoid')
(5, 0.5, 'precomputed')
(5, 0.6, 'linear')
(5, 0.6, 'poly')
(5, 0.6, 'rbf')
(5, 0.6, 'sigmoid')
(5, 0.6, 'precomputed')
(5, 0.7, 'linear')
(5, 0.7, 'poly')
(5, 0.7, 'rbf')
(5, 0.7, 'sigmoid')
(5, 0.7, 'precomputed')
(5, 0.8, 'linear')
(5, 0.8, 'poly')
(5, 0.8, 'rbf')
(5, 0.8, 'sigmoid')
(5, 0.8, 'precomputed')
(5, 0.9, 'linear')
(5, 0.9, 'poly')
(5, 0.9, 'rbf')
(5, 0.9, 'sigmoid')
(5, 0.9, 'precomputed')
(5, 1, 'linear')
(5, 1, 'poly')
(5, 1, 'rbf')
(5, 1, 'sigmoid')
(5, 1, 'precomputed')
(10, 'scale', 'linear')
(10, 'scale', 'poly')
(10, 'scale', 'rbf')
(10, 'scale', 'sigmoid')
(10, 'scale', 'precomputed')
(10, 'auto', 'linear')
(10, 'auto', 'poly')
(10, 'auto', 'rbf')
(10, 'auto', 'sigmoid')
(10, 'auto', 'precomputed')
(10, 0.001, 'linear')
(10, 0.001, 'poly')
(10, 0.001, 'rbf')
(10, 0.001, 'sigmoid')
(10, 0.001, 'precomputed')
(10, 0.1, 'linear')
(10, 0.1, 'poly')
(10, 0.1, 'rbf')
(10, 0.1, 'sigmoid')
(10, 0.1, 'precomputed')
(10, 0.5, 'linear')
(10, 0.5, 'poly')
(10, 0.5, 'rbf')
(10, 0.5, 'sigmoid')
(10, 0.5, 'precomputed')
(10, 0.6, 'linear')
(10, 0.6, 'poly')
(10, 0.6, 'rbf')
(10, 0.6, 'sigmoid')
(10, 0.6, 'precomputed')
(10, 0.7, 'linear')
(10, 0.7, 'poly')
(10, 0.7, 'rbf')
(10, 0.7, 'sigmoid')
(10, 0.7, 'precomputed')
(10, 0.8, 'linear')
(10, 0.8, 'poly')
(10, 0.8, 'rbf')
(10, 0.8, 'sigmoid')
(10, 0.8, 'precomputed')
(10, 0.9, 'linear')
(10, 0.9, 'poly')
(10, 0.9, 'rbf')
(10, 0.9, 'sigmoid')
(10, 0.9, 'precomputed')
(10, 1, 'linear')
(10, 1, 'poly')
(10, 1, 'rbf')
(10, 1, 'sigmoid')
(10, 1, 'precomputed')
(20, 'scale', 'linear')
(20, 'scale', 'poly')
(20, 'scale', 'rbf')
(20, 'scale', 'sigmoid')
(20, 'scale', 'precomputed')
(20, 'auto', 'linear')
(20, 'auto', 'poly')
(20, 'auto', 'rbf')
(20, 'auto', 'sigmoid')
(20, 'auto', 'precomputed')
(20, 0.001, 'linear')
(20, 0.001, 'poly')
(20, 0.001, 'rbf')
(20, 0.001, 'sigmoid')
(20, 0.001, 'precomputed')
(20, 0.1, 'linear')
(20, 0.1, 'poly')
(20, 0.1, 'rbf')
(20, 0.1, 'sigmoid')
(20, 0.1, 'precomputed')
(20, 0.5, 'linear')
(20, 0.5, 'poly')
(20, 0.5, 'rbf')
(20, 0.5, 'sigmoid')
(20, 0.5, 'precomputed')
(20, 0.6, 'linear')
(20, 0.6, 'poly')
(20, 0.6, 'rbf')
(20, 0.6, 'sigmoid')
(20, 0.6, 'precomputed')
(20, 0.7, 'linear')
(20, 0.7, 'poly')
(20, 0.7, 'rbf')
(20, 0.7, 'sigmoid')
(20, 0.7, 'precomputed')
(20, 0.8, 'linear')
(20, 0.8, 'poly')
(20, 0.8, 'rbf')
(20, 0.8, 'sigmoid')
(20, 0.8, 'precomputed')
(20, 0.9, 'linear')
(20, 0.9, 'poly')
(20, 0.9, 'rbf')
(20, 0.9, 'sigmoid')
(20, 0.9, 'precomputed')
(20, 1, 'linear')
(20, 1, 'poly')
(20, 1, 'rbf')
(20, 1, 'sigmoid')
(20, 1, 'precomputed')
(50, 'scale', 'linear')
(50, 'scale', 'poly')
(50, 'scale', 'rbf')
(50, 'scale', 'sigmoid')
(50, 'scale', 'precomputed')
(50, 'auto', 'linear')
(50, 'auto', 'poly')
(50, 'auto', 'rbf')
(50, 'auto', 'sigmoid')
(50, 'auto', 'precomputed')
(50, 0.001, 'linear')
(50, 0.001, 'poly')
(50, 0.001, 'rbf')
(50, 0.001, 'sigmoid')
(50, 0.001, 'precomputed')
(50, 0.1, 'linear')
(50, 0.1, 'poly')
(50, 0.1, 'rbf')
(50, 0.1, 'sigmoid')
(50, 0.1, 'precomputed')
(50, 0.5, 'linear')
(50, 0.5, 'poly')
(50, 0.5, 'rbf')
(50, 0.5, 'sigmoid')
(50, 0.5, 'precomputed')
(50, 0.6, 'linear')
(50, 0.6, 'poly')
(50, 0.6, 'rbf')
(50, 0.6, 'sigmoid')
(50, 0.6, 'precomputed')
(50, 0.7, 'linear')
(50, 0.7, 'poly')
(50, 0.7, 'rbf')
(50, 0.7, 'sigmoid')
(50, 0.7, 'precomputed')
(50, 0.8, 'linear')
(50, 0.8, 'poly')
(50, 0.8, 'rbf')
(50, 0.8, 'sigmoid')
(50, 0.8, 'precomputed')
(50, 0.9, 'linear')
(50, 0.9, 'poly')
(50, 0.9, 'rbf')
(50, 0.9, 'sigmoid')
(50, 0.9, 'precomputed')
(50, 1, 'linear')
(50, 1, 'poly')
(50, 1, 'rbf')
(50, 1, 'sigmoid')
(50, 1, 'precomputed')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 30, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You are iterating over a tuple in your second loop, but you are treating it as a integer index variable. You are trying to access `chl[(1, 'scale', 'linear')][0]` which is not valid syntax.

Comment: Please also consider to use question titles that actually describe your problems, otherwise other user will have a hard time finding them if they encounter a similar problem.